# Как обработать объект в рекурсии JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, рекурсия

Как правильно обработать объект в рекурсии, чтобы можно было искать **min**, **max** среди **value**?

структура объекта:

```
Node = {
    value: <number>,
    children: [Node]
}
```

функция:

```
const deepMap = (obj) =>{

        //maxValue =(maxValue.value < obj.value) ? obj : maxValue;
        console.log( obj);
        obj.children ? obj.children.map(item => deepMap(item)) : obj;

};
```

часть объекта

```
var graph = {
    value: 75,
    children: [{
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            value: 35,
            children: [{
                value: 35,
                children: [{
                    value: 66,
                    children: [{
                        value: 29,
                        children: [{value: 85}]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь пример данных и результата. В принципе, кроме отсутствующего return код делает то, что ты и хочешь

Comment: @Grundy здесь больше вопрос в том, можно ли обработать объект в этой же функции, чтоб найти максимум. Правильно ли это для функционального подхода.

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под обработать?

Comment: @Grundy найти  max среди value
скинула скрин объекта

Comment: не не не, пример входной даты лучше текстом, а не картинкой, и не все 100-200 элементов, а 3-5 чтобы просто было видно структуру, и понятно что в итоге должно было получиться

Comment: var graph = {
    value: 75,
    children: [{
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            value: 35,
            children: [{
                value: 35,
                children: [{
                    value: 66,
                    children: [{
                        value: 29,
                        children: [{value: 85}]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

Comment: Добавь это в сам вопрос.

Comment: Для этого примера функция должна 85 вернуть?

Comment: @Grundy max 85, да

Answer (score 2):

В примере кода в вопросе отсутствует `return`, следовательно данная функция ничего не выводит, но она уже пробегает по всем элементам в графе.

Первое что нужно изменить: добавить `return`, который будет возвращать нужное значение.

*Нужным* в данном случае является максимум из нескольких чисел: значения поля `value`, и значений из поля `children`.

Применяя функцию `deepMap` к каждому элементу массива `children` можно на каждом уровне иметь список максимальных значений.

Для нахождения максимального числа из нескольких можно применить функцию [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), а так же [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), позволяющей удобно передать в нее массив.

Так как поле `children` может отсутствовать, нужно добавить соответствующую проверку и в случае ее выполнения сразу возвращать `value`.

Приняв все замечания, функцию можно изменить так:

```
const deepMap = (obj) => {
  if (!obj.children) return obj.value; // если нет детей - сразу вернуть value
  var maxChildren = obj.children.map(deepMap); // получаем максимальных из детей
  return Math.max(obj.value, ...maxChildren); // возвращаем максимальное из значений.
};
```

Если убрать локальные переменные и `if` можно получить следующий вариант:

```
function deepMax(obj){
    return Math.max(obj.value, ...(obj.children||[]).map(deepMax));
}
```

Пример:

```js
const deepMap = (obj) => {
  if (!obj.children) return obj.value; // если нет детей - сразу вернуть value
  var maxChildren = obj.children.map(deepMap); // получаем максимальных из детей
  return Math.max(obj.value, ...maxChildren); // возвращаем максимальное из значений.
};

var graph = {
  value: 75,
  children: [{
    value: 18,
    children: [{
      value: 35,
      children: [{
        value: 35,
        children: [{
          value: 66,
          children: [{
            value: 29,
            children: [{
              value: 85
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

console.log(deepMap(graph));
```

Answer (score 2):

Для данной структуры я бы предложил такое решение:

```js
const graph = {
    value: 75,
    children: [{
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            value: 35,
            children: [{
                value: 35,
                children: [{
                    value: 66,
                    children: [{
                        value: 29,
                        children: [{value: 85}]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

// Функция deepMap рекурсивно обходит дерево obj
// Второй параметр func - необходимая функция сравнения
function deepMap(obj, func){
    if(obj.children){ // Если есть потомки - то уходим в рекурсию
      let res = obj.value;
      // Рекурсивно проходим по всем потомкам и вычисляем результат
      for(let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
         res = func(res, deepMap(obj.children[i], func));
      }  
      return res;
    } else { // Нет потомков - возвращаем значение 
      return obj.value
    }  
  }
  
  console.log(`Max result for graph is: ${deepMap(graph, Math.max)}`);

  console.log(`Min result for graph is: ${deepMap(graph, Math.min)}`);
```